# How to plotting a data frame with scatter plot in multiple columns by index?

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, scatter

I have a data frame with some columns and I would like to plot the frequency of the value each column

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['0','0','0','2','0','0','0','3'],
               'B': ['0','0','0','4','3','0','0','4'],
               'C': ['1','1','2','8','9','6','1','10']})
df
```

For now, I have the solution code

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 5), dpi=80)
plt.plot(df.A,'rx', df.B, 'g^--', df.C, 'bs-')
plt.show()
```

But, I would the result like as follow:
[image]

Is there anyone can help me?

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get your question, you want to plot every row as a scatter plot?

Comment: yes, I want to plot every value counted as a scatter plot. In particular, I want the y-axis to be the parameter from the column as like figure.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)

data = [[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3],
       [0,0,0,4,3,0,0,4],
       [1,1,2,8,9,6,1,10]]
np_data = np.array(data)
indexes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
columns = list('ABC')
df = pd.DataFrame(np_data.transpose(), index=indexes, columns=columns)
print(df)
df[columns] = df[columns].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')
plt.figure()
df.plot()
plt.savefig("image.png")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I want to y-axis should be the name of the column so we only know the value of each row without the frequency

Comment: I don't understand what you want... Sorry, could you give me some example by hand drawing?

Comment: It's okay, I was uploaded my handwriting explanation https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgnFX.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying to plot the data frame as, like bellow, I am writing the simple code and I got the picture as what I want to do it. But I need to some suggestion to make for-loop or boolean to apply on the big data.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['0','0','0','2','0','0','0','3','0'],
               'B': ['0','0','0','4','3','0','0','4','2'],
               'C': ['1','1','2','8','9','6','1','10','3']})
df1

plt.figure(figsize=(5, 6), dpi=80)
plt.plot(df1.loc[0,:],'ro', df1.loc[1,:], 'ro', df1.loc[2,:], 'ro', df1.loc[3,:], 
    'bs-', df1.loc[4,:], 'g^--', df1.loc[8,:], 'g^--')
plt.plot(df1.loc[5,:], 'ro', df1.loc[6,:], 'ro', df1.loc[7,:], 'bs-')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MTfr.png)